# Less terrible way to update DOM dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, websocket

I'm creating a widget inside an iframe, a websocket receives some trades at a fast rate. I want to display the last 10 trades received by the websocket in a table (for example). what is the best way to do that (most optimized method):

1.I Rewrite my whole tbody each time a trade is received with .innerHTML

2. I update the DOM by adding and removing nodes depending on the updates (but it will happen also a lot of times).

I can't use anything but plain javascript , no library, jquery ..etc
What method should I use (fastest, simplest...) ? Any other idea ?

thanks!

Edit: Some interesting doc on this topic suggested by @Myst http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think a grid sort of structure, then my approach would be:

- assign each `<td>` cell a unique ID
- in the JavaScript function, use `document.getElementById()` to get a reference to each cell that needs updating
- use `innerHTML` to update those cells

Accessing an element using `id` is the fastest way, and updating with `.innerHTML` will also be the quickest method.

Comment: So the first method, I was going this way too. Thank you

Comment: I would also consider the stacking order for the DOM. Every update causes a re-rendering of the DOM. Having the objects with a fixed size (maybe overflow is visible) and printed on a "detached" layer, would minimize the re-rendering (much like CSS `transform`'s performance vs. other animation techniques).

Comment: @Myst i'm not sure exactly what you are saying, do you have an example you could link me to ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard - There's a wonderful [overview about DOM layers and rendering considerations here](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/). You can read more [about DOM layers and rendering optimizations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/).

Comment: @void - Would you consider adding the links related to DOM layer rendering in your answer? I know, from experience, that this can have a big impact on rendering speeds and it isn't an issue enough developers are aware of. Most front-end developers aren't aware that layer optimizations can boost speeds dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's difficult to answer about performance without more details. I guess the answer depends on the number of trades received compared to the number of trades already shown, and on the cost of showing a new trade.

Here is my attempt at painting only new trades received (sorry, I don't know what a trade is). We could play with `repaintTrades` to compare different options :

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container'),
    queue = [],
    nbTradesToShow = 50,
    nbNewTrades = 80,
    _tradeId = 0,
    _tradeNames = ['hello', 'bonjour', 'guten Tag', 'hola', 'buongiorno']

function repaintTrades() {
  var firstToKeepIndex, i = 0
  queue = queue.slice(-nbTradesToShow)
  firstToKeepIndex = container.children.length + queue.length - nbTradesToShow
  while (i++ < firstToKeepIndex) 
    container.removeChild(container.firstElementChild)  
  // add new trades
  queue.forEach(createTradeRow)
  queue = []
}      

function receive(trades) {
  queue = queue.concat(trades)
  window.requestAnimationFrame(repaintTrades)  
}

function websocketTrades() {
  var nbTrades = Math.floor(Math.random() * nbNewTrades),
      i = 0,
      trades = []
  console.debug(nbTrades, ' trades will be created')
  while (i++ < nbTrades) trades.push({
    id: _tradeId++,
    name: _tradeNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]
  })
  setTimeout(websocketTrades, 1000)
  receive(trades)
}


function createTradeRow(trade) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr'),
      cellId = document.createElement('td'),
      cellName = document.createElement('td')

    cellId.textContent = trade.id
    cellName.textContent = trade.name
    row.appendChild(cellId)
    row.appendChild(cellName)
    container.appendChild(row)
}



websocketTrades()
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>id</td><td>name</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="container">
     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the second option, but don't you think it would kill performances ? I went with the first method innerHTML based

Comment: I think it depends on the complexity of adding new trades, and the ratio between existing trades to keep and new trades to add on each update (with the first option, you delete every trade, even those you still need and that you will have to create again). I tried to compare both approaches but the results seem strangely close from each other : http://jsperf.com/partialvscompletererendering Not sure of my test case...